# Get ID of updated entry on Update trigger - mutating table error

Tags: oracle, plsql, mutating-table

I'm trying to create an update trigger but I keep bumping on the "mutating table" error. The main idea is a sell&buy database with user ratings.
Basically I want to, everytime a rating on the PRODUTOS table is updated, recalculate the seller's rating. 
I'm trying the following trigger (and versions of it) but it's no getting anywhere..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER actualiza_rating_vend
AFTER UPDATE OF RATING_VENDEDOR
ON PRODUTOS
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    CURSOR prod IS
        SELECT ID_USER,RATING_VENDEDOR, ID_COMPRADOR, RATING_COMPRADOR
        FROM   PRODUTOS
        WHERE  PRODUTOS.ID_USER = :NEW.ID_USER
        OR     PRODUTOS.ID_COMPRADOR = :NEW.ID_USER;
     contador NUMBER;
     soma     NUMBER;
     res      NUMBER;
     linha    prod%ROWTYPE;
     username  varchar2(255);
     BEGIN
     res := 0;
     contador := 0;
     fetch prod into linha;  
     username := :NEW.ID_USER;
         while prod%found loop
          if(linha.ID_user = username)
          then
            soma := soma + linha.RATING_VENDEDOR;
          else
            soma := soma + linha.RATING_COMPRADOR;
          end if;
          contador := contador + 1;       
          fetch prod into linha;
        end loop;
    close prod;
         res := soma / contador;
         update USERS set USERS.RATING = res where USERS.ID_USER = username;
  end;
```

Can somebody give me a hint how can I select only the entries where the ID_USER value equals the ID_USER of the updated entry?..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You talk about the `DEALS` table in the text of your question.  But your trigger has no reference to that table.  I'm assuming that the trigger is correct and that the text of the question is in error but it would be helpful if you could clarify that.

Comment: Also, is the `UPDATE` on the `RATING_VENDEDOR` table coming from another trigger (or code called from another trigger) on either `PRODUTOS` or `USERS`?

Comment: @JustinCave sorry, I wrote Deals because 'produtos' is a portuguese word and it could be strange (but I made it worse, lol) I've edited to the correct table name. And no, the update on the RATING_VENDEDOR is not coming from another trigger, it's a direct sql update command..again, sorry

Comment: If the `UPDATE` is not coming from another trigger (or something called by another trigger), I'm hard-pressed to see how this would throw a mutating table exception since it is not trying to query the table that the trigger is defined on.  Either the `UPDATE` is being issued (directly or indirectly) from another trigger or the mutating table exception is not being thrown from this trigger.

Comment: Do you really want to be recalculating it from the trigger anyway; would a view that calculates it on the fly  (or materialized view) work for this? May depend on update and query frequency I suppose.

Comment: @JustinCave the update is just a normal update sql command..I get the following error after trying the update command (on which the trigger is set):
 ORA-06512: at "TRABALHO_CAPELO.ACTUALIZA_RATING_VENDEDOR", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TRABALHO_CAPELO.ACTUALIZA_RATING_VENDEDOR'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"

Comment: @AlexPoole I guess I could calculate it through a view...but I have to update the RATING column on the USERS table, that's why I've made the trigger..Using a view, I'd have to calculate the new value and then manually update it on the USERS table..right (I'm using Codeigniter by the way)? I though that was the point of using triggers. But I'm starting so I can be wrong..

Comment: You know that the name of the trigger in the error message does not match the name of the trigger you posted, right?  Is there another trigger in the system with the name referenced in the error message?

Comment: @JustinCave yeah, that's just because I changed the name of the trigger after I posted this here...No, the other trigger I have doesn' affect any of these tables (USERS or PRODUCTS).. I'm trying to solve this by using compound triggers. This kind of triggers seem to let me select rows from the updated table but I can' use the :new.columname feature so it's no use..

Comment: Let's take a step back.  Can you post the DDL to create the tables in question (simplified versions that demonstrate the problem), the code to create this trigger and whatever other triggers are necessary to replicate your problem, the DML to insert a few rows of sample data, and the `UPDATE` statement you are executing that generates the exception?  Or create a sqlfiddle with this information.  Give us enough information to replicate your issue on our machines.

Answer (score 0):

If the ratings in the table `USERS` are up to date, you only have to add the latest changed rating:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER actualiza_rating_vend
  AFTER UPDATE ON produtos FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE users 
      SET user_rating = user_rating + :new.rating_vendedor - :old.rating_vendedor
    WHERE id_user = :new.id_user;

   UPDATE users 
      SET user_rating = user_rating + :new.rating_comprador - :old.rating_comprador
   WHERE id_user = :new.id_comprador;

END actualiza_rating_vend;
```

/

Comment: That way I'm only updating the value of rating_vendedor on PRODUTOS and not on the USERS table..Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly: Each user has a rating value, which comes from the average ratings of the item he sold. So, when he receives a new rating, I have to recalculate that average "global" rating..

Comment: I would not recalculate the average for every single update, but take advantage of average = sum / count. The trigger above sums up the ratings, you only have to add a counting column and you have the average without recalculation.